# NOT IN SQL ( Quero selecionar pilotos que nunca fizeram uma certa rota) como?

Tags: sql

Quero selecionar os pilotos (neste caso comandantes ou copilotos) que nunca fizeram voos com a rota 12345 . De momento o SQL está a retornar todos os pilotos  e eu quero que retorne apenas o 18200 o 25100 e o 25169 . Alguem sabe o que estou a fazer mal?

```
SELECT pl.id
FROM   Piloto pl
WHERE  pl.id NOT IN (
     SELECT ( pl2.id OR pl3.id )
     FROM   Piloto pl2,Piloto pl3, Voo v, Rota r           
     WHERE  (pl2.id = v.id_comandante OR pl3.id = v.id_copiloto)                       
          AND v.cod_rota = r.cod_rota                 
          AND r.cod_rota = 12345 )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De novo????????

Comment: Dessa vez mudou os voooooooooooooooooo .....

Comment: Sim, ainda nao consegui resolver o meu problema.. no ultimo post estava apenas a selecionar os comandantes, dai nao estar a resultar, agora ja estou a selecionar ambos. Nao sei é porque e que me continua a retornar todos os id's...

Comment: Por que você não está fazendo `join`? Não foi dito isso na outra pergunta?

Comment: @Esteves, tenha paciência com suas perguntas, e espere uma resposta que esteja de acordo com o que vc precisa, se não foi claro na pergunta clique em Editar e altere de forma que fique clara, Mas não fique criando um monte de pergunta para o mesmo assunto .   Faça um [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Eu ainda não vejo o motivo de abrir outra pergunta se o problema ainda é o mesmo da outra. Estou votando para fechar como duplicada.

Comment: Nao usei join porque nao me é permitido. Desculpem, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Pilotos que fizeram a rota x

```
select id_copiloto
from Voo 
where 
cod_rota = 12345
union 
select  id_comandante
from Voo 
where cod_rota = 12345
```

Pilotos não que fizeram a rota x

```
select *
from pilotos
where id_piloto not in (select id_copiloto
                        from Voo 
                        where cod_rota = 12345
                        union 
                        select  id_comandante
                        from Voo 
                       where cod_rota = 12345)
```